# Fail to get the file in springboot static content

Tags: spring-boot, static, filenotfoundexception

I fail to get the spring boot static file when I write the path like this:

```
 private static final String FILE_PATH = "/resources/data/user.json";
```

It turns out that FileNotFound. How should I write the path?
[image: project structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use ClasspathResource

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/static/data/user.json");
File file = resource.getFile();
```

Comment: Sorry, but how can I write content in the json file.